# Python Dataframe Duplicated Columns while Merging multple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I have a main dataframe and a sub dataframe. I want to merge each column in sub dataframe into main dataframe with main dataframe column as a reference. I have successfully arrived at my desired answer, except that I see duplicated columns of the main dataframe. Below are the my expected and present answers.

Present solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ref':[1,2,3,4]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3],'Z':[1,2]})

df = [df.merge(df1[col_name],left_on='Ref',right_on=col_name,how='left') for col_name in df1.columns]
df = pd.concat(df,axis=1)
df = 
   Ref    A   Ref    Z
0    1  NaN     1  1.0
1    2  2.0     2  2.0
2    3  3.0     3  NaN
3    4  NaN     4  NaN
```

Expected Answer:

```
df = 
   Ref    A    Z
0    1  NaN  1.0
1    2  2.0  2.0
2    3  3.0  NaN
3    4  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting 'Ref' col as index while getting dataframe list. (And resetting index such that you get back Ref as a column)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ref':[1,2,3,4]}) 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,3],'Z':[1,2]})


df = [df.merge(df1[col_name],left_on='Ref',right_on=col_name,how='left').set_index('Ref') for col_name in df1.columns]
df = pd.concat(df,axis=1)

df = df.reset_index()

        Ref  A   Z
        1   NaN 1.0
        2   2.0 2.0 
        3   3.0 NaN 
        4   NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Use `duplicated`:

```
>>> df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
   Ref    A    Z
0    1  NaN  1.0
1    2  2.0  2.0
2    3  3.0  NaN
3    4  NaN  NaN
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use:

```
# Your code
...
df = pd.concat(df, axis=1)

# Use pop and insert to cleanup your dataframe
df.insert(0, 'Ref', df.pop('Ref').iloc[:, 0])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Ref    A    Z
0    1  NaN  1.0
1    2  2.0  2.0
2    3  3.0  NaN
3    4  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Nice one. The answer here deletes the multiple and keeps the first one. correct? I thought about it but have one new line of code. Do you think it can be done in existing code by tweaking it?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The option with `set_index` is a good alternative. Check the answer of @AndreaIerardi. I updated my answer with a simpler method

Comment: You can also replace your whole code by: `df.merge(df1.melt(), left_on='Ref', right_on='value', how='left').pivot_table('value', 'Ref', 'variable').reindex(df['Ref']).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

This is a reduction process. Instead of the list comprehension use for - loop, or even `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda x, y : x.merge(df1[y],left_on='Ref',right_on=y,how='left'), df1.columns, df)

   Ref    A    Z
0    1  NaN  1.0
1    2  2.0  2.0
2    3  3.0  NaN
3    4  NaN  NaN
```

The above is similar to:

```
for y in df1.columns:
    df = df.merge(df1[y],left_on='Ref',right_on=y,how='left')
df
 
   Ref    A    Z
0    1  NaN  1.0
1    2  2.0  2.0
2    3  3.0  NaN
3    4  NaN  NaN
```